# tinyMCE triggerSave not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tinymce

Im trying to submit a form with a tinyMCE textarea. Im submitting the form via javascript, and in order to do this i know you have to call tinyMCE.triggerSave to copy the contents of the editor to the hidden textarea it replaces. For the life of me i can NOT get tinyMCE.triggerSave to do ANYTHING. I know its not because i run the command from the safari and firefox debug tools and nothing in the DOM changes.

Other than this problem tinyMCE seems to be working fine, the form shows up and works. I just cant submit it.

EDIT:
even if i use a standard form submit button it does not pick up the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I included the tinyMCE js files twice. I had

```
= include_tiny_mce_if_needed
```

in my application template, and i had

```
- content_for(:head, include_tiny_mce_if_needed)
```

in my view file ...
BAD

Caused me hours of frustration.

Answer (score 7):

You can also run into this problem if you initialize the same editor twice using tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, id);

No error will be shown but the triggerSave function will fail silently.

Answer (score -3):

It might not just be that you included js files twice.  I just ran into a similar issue and did a quick benchtest of it.  Approx 1 in 100 times triggerSave() failed silently ... once it fails you're done.  It won't work again until you reload/rerun a full tinymce.init()

Moral of the story, don't trust triggerSave()!  Sooner or later you will end up losing critical data.